# OLS in R with Marginal Effects

Tags: r, regression, marginal-effects

I am looking for a code to estimate the following equation as OLS with panal data:

∆Yjt = α∆Xjt + τt + ujt

where ∆ is the change of Y and X over time, j a sector, t the time, τ a set of time dummies and u the error term.

I'm a beginner in R programming and unfortunately I can't find the appropriate code to take into account ∆.

Does anyone have an idea how I could run the regression?

Thanks for your time and help

Comment: Probably better to also ask this question on cross validate, please provide some data

Comment: My understanding is that by logging both the Y ans x variables you could reach this equation but I am not sure about that

Comment: If you search for the `plm` package, and then look into a "first difference" model, you should be able to find how to do this. Or your can repost the question with data and references to plm and first difference.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome, lisa-marie. As Jeremy pointed out, try `plm`. It provides some sample data. I assume that "OLS with panel data" implies a pooled regression? Compare it to a fixed effects regression:

```
library("plm")
data("Produc", package = "plm")

# Pooled Regression    
pooled <- plm(log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp,
          data = Produc, 
          index = c("state","year"),
          method="pooling")

# Fixed Effects Regression    
fe <- plm(log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp,
          data = Produc, 
          index = c("state","year"),
          method="within")
```

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

My solution for the problem was finally:
I calculated changes ∆ with tidyverse and was able to solve the problem easily.

Marco's solution with log would have been even easier, but because I had to deal with negative values I could not use it.

Thanks everyone for your help!